# Checking device storage space on iOS device

Tags: ios, swift, mobile-application

I am developing an iOS mobile application using Swift. In this I have a requirement that before the app gets installed it should check for device storage space , and if there is not enough storage space(as per the defined threshold space to be there for app installation) then accordingly a pop-up should be shown to the user. How can I implement this?
Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

That is impossible. You cannot run code on a device before your app is installed.

The Store app will check if there is enough room on the device to install the actual files you ship in your bundle. It won't check for "extra" space for you.